# SQL select rows with the same column's value

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Good afternoon you everyone! Could you help me? :)

**DATABASE SAMPLE**:

```
ID  Catalog Code  Description Type  Supplier  Supplier Code

1   6083          TV LG 32    tv    lg        ud28f1137ka-ga-i2-tr  
1   6083          TV LG 32    tv    samsung   asfb1145-ssd          # select it
2   6129          Phone 5X    phone apple     mics_rp
2   6129          Phone 5X    phone htc       nco_p13 961-x
2   6129          Phone 5X    phone nokia     n_41s
3   6210          Friezer     agd   samsung   asfb1145-ssd          # found match
                                                                  it has the same
                                                                  `Supplier Code`
```

The above `ID` is assigned to `Catalog Code`. All fields are `VARCHAR` except for `ID`. Could be empty.

**WHAT I'D LIKE TO DO:**

Select e.g `Catalog Code = 6083` and get all other `Catalog Codes` **IF** one of `Supplier Codes` is the same.

So I should get: `Catalog Code = 6210` (last row) because it has the same `Supplier Code` as `6083` (first row).

**MY POOR ATTEMPT:**

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM `TABLE` a
  WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
            FROM `TABLE` b
            WHERE b.`Catalog Code` = '6083'
            AND (
                  a.`Supplier Code` NOT IN ('') 
              AND a.`Supplier Code` IN b.`Supplier Code`
                )
        )
```

**NEED FOR DESIGN IMPROVEMENTS**

My real DB has over **100 000 rows**. I feel the DB design needs improvements but which ones?

`INDEXES`, `PRIMARY KEY`, second DB with `FOREIGN KEY`?

Comment: When does a 0 appear in what column(s), and when does a '' appear in what column(s)? Does an id always appear with the same code? Does a code always appear with the same id? Your question is not clear. You also seem to use "db" when you mean "table".

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query more like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.supplier_code in (select t2.supplier_code
                          from t t2
                          where t2.catalog_code = '6083'
                         );
```

Your code is rather strange.  Why would you have `not in ('')`?  This is redundant.  Then on the second `in`, you need a list, not a column value.  In fact, just `=` is sufficient.

For performance, you want an index on `t(catalog_code, supplier_code)`.

Comment: `NOT IN` because some column values are empty strings or 0 or I'd like to exclude something - maybe there's better way to do that.

Comment: I remember back when we had joins. Those were the days.

Comment: I know `JOIN` should be used - I just can't wrap my head around this specific problem (connect dots). Could you help us with that? :)

Answer (score 0):

For this particular question how about you use 2 table .

1) contains catalog code details.(keep catalog code as primary key)

2) Supplier details  (keep ID as primary key- 1,2,3)

3) catalog code and supplier code-ID mapping (foreign key from both tables) .. both are integer values so queries will be bit faster because of comparison.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY` must be unique and `CATALOG CODE` is not. The same applies to `ID` in this DB. But I can add new column `PK_ID` but I can't go further in my head with it - what's next? That's why I'm asking for help :)

Comment: divide your table into 3 tables. where 1st will have only catalog code , desc, type  and... 2nd table will have ID-integer , supplier , supplier code and ...3rd table will have catalog code and supplier-ID

Comment: To make things clear (I'm learning it): 3rd table with `SUPPLIER CODE ID` as `FOREIGN KEY` referencing to `SUPPLIER CODE` in 2nd table?

Comment: "SUPPLIER CODE ID" as foreign key of  " ID"  in 2nd table. because ID is primary key in 2nd table.